# Entity reference by title

Tags: entities, feeds

I'm using the Feeds module and entity references heavily on my site to add, update, and link content. Unfortunately, the data I'm using has a number of records that are named the same, which causes issues when matching Entity References through GUID.

Is there a way to import entity reference fields through Feeds but using title and content-type instead?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found an answer to this problem.

Using the Feeds Tamper module, I can add use the Entity Fields Query Finder plugin to lookup against any other field belonging to a particular content type.

In my case I'm saving the lookup key I need in a field, and then matching against that field & content type.

Comment: nice, glad to hear.

Answer (score 0):

> Title **and** content-type

By default, there is no way to do that.

So you have 2 choices:

A) Go by the referenced nid instead.

B) Create a custom parser, see the [The developer's guide to Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/node/622700).

Comment: Thanks!

Going by nid isn't going to be possible as I'm not storing that anywhere within my import data to be able to reference it, so it looks like I'll have to explore option B.